# Google Cloud Platform - Alerts not triggering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, alerts

Im trying to set up monitoring in Google Cloud Platform , where if I get one type of log for more than 50 times in 1 hour , it should trigger an email .

Alert configuration that I tried setting up :

```
"conditionThreshold": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "3600s", // sum the count of logs for one hour 
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_SUM"
          }
        ],
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
        "duration": "3600s", // If in an hour we get 50 calls of same type then trigger
        "filter": "my metric type and revision type  check[enter image description here][1]",
        "thresholdValue": 50, // number of calls after which the alert has to trigger
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        }
      }
```

Sometimes it triggers and sometimes not , Im not able to understand the variables threshold , period , align especially that condition part in UI which says `above 50 for 1 hour`  . What does these variables means?

Went through the doc but still confused.

Thanks in advance !